# Application freezes when changing windows Keyboard layout

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, ado

The below code makes application freeze when changing focus from Edit1 to Edit2 after creating the thread.

Steps to reproduce:

- Click Create thread button
- Switch focus between Edit1 / Edit2.

I think the ADO object creation inside the thread is causing the application to freeze.

Does anyone have any idea of the what is the exact problem?

Note : I guess the problem occurs when default input language is changed.
Win xp - Text Service and Input langauges dialog - Default input language.

Same issue as :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/1d27c2ad-7ef1-45e9-b9af-6bfb458c1165

**pas file**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ADODB, SyncObjs, ActiveX,
  ComObj, Menus, StdCtrls;

type

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FEvent : TEvent;
    adoConnection : TADOConnection;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ASuspended : boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure TextEdit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TextEdit2Enter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    MyThread : TMyThread;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TMyThread }

constructor TMyThread.Create(ASuspended: boolean
                            );
begin
  inherited Create(ASuspended);
  FEvent := TEvent.Create(nil,
                          false,
                          false,
                          'test'
                          );
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FEvent);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  CoInitializeEx(nil,
                 COINIT_MULTITHREADED
                );
  try
    adoConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
    FEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
    adoConnection.Free;
  finally
    CoUnInitialize;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm1.TextEdit1Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadKeyboardLayout(PChar(IntToHex(1081, 8)), KLF_ACTIVATE);
end;

procedure TForm1.TextEdit2Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadKeyboardLayout(PChar(IntToHex(1043, 8)), KLF_ACTIVATE);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  MyThread.FEvent.SetEvent;
  MyThread.Terminate;
  FreeAndNil(MyThread);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyThread := TMyThread.Create(true);
end;

end.
```

**form file**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 115
  ClientWidth = 147
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Edit1'
    OnEnter = TextEdit1Enter
  end
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Left = 8
    Top = 35
    Width = 121
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Edit2'
    OnEnter = TextEdit2Enter
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 62
    Width = 121
    Height = 45
    Caption = 'Create Thread'
    TabOrder = 2
    WordWrap = True
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

Comment: `TADOConnection` should not use `MainForm` as its component owner, for one thing; its constructor and destructor will notify the owner, and it will receive notifications about other components being freed (so it can nil properties that refer to them); but this mechanism is not thread-safe and interacting with the connection on a different thread to the VCL is asking for trouble. Use a nil owner at least.

Comment: FWIW, I tried your test code and it doesn't deadlock on my machine.

Comment: @Barry Kelly : you are right.  I changed it to nil.  But the main problem how come it is locking the application.  I feel, there is some kind of race condition here which I am not able to find!

Comment: @Barry Kelly : The idea behind this is, it makes use of thread to fetch data and posts the updates to main thread.  The code shown here is only to reproduce the problem. So no problem using ado inside a thread.  The only issue that came up is when using LoadKeyboardLayout from main thread.

Comment: @Pavan - and also if you have Windows 7, check the note on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646305%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `Starting from Windows 7/2008, calling ActivateKeyboardLayout can be quite slow (around 0.5 second on our tests). It should therefore not be used frequently. Instead, it should be called once when the application is loaded, and store the returned HKL on some globally accessible location.`

Comment: @Pavan - and please, don't forget to tell us how is it going. You have quite a lot opened questions and we are building these sites as a big resource for future usage. And if any of the answers doesn't help answer your questions, then post your own solution and accept it. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

In pas file change the line

```
 CoInitializeEx(nil,
                 COINIT_MULTITHREADED
                );
```

to

```
  CoInitializeEx(nil,
                 COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED
                );
```

and

```
  FEvent := TEvent.Create(nil,
                          false,
                          false,
                          'test'
                          );
```

to

```
  FEvent := TEvent.Create(nil,
                          false,
                          false,
                          'test',
                          true
                          );
```